# Js event handling on overlaped elements isn't work. is it about the scope? about true/false?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, scope

Ok. Let me tell you my problem so simple.

When I give some event(like 'click') on element, some case it doesn't work.

For example, I give trigger on id 'abc'...

```
 event of this element works fine : <li id="abc"> 123123123 </li>

 But this isn't : <li id="abc"> <b> 123123 </b> </li>
```

I don't know why.

Below is the code :

```
entrance = document.getElementById('entrance');
joinSite = document.getElementById('joinSite');

// Event controller for multi browsers.
var Event = {
    add: function(element, type, handler) {
        if (element.addEventListener) {
            element.addEventListener(type, handler, true);
        } else if (element.attachEvent) {
            element.attachEvent("on" + type, handler);
        } else {
            element["on" + type] = handler;
        }
    },

    remove: function(element, type, handler) {
        if (element.removeEventListener) {
            element.removeEventListener(type, handler, true);
        } else if (element.detachEvent) {
            element.detachEvent("on" + type, handler);
        } else {
            element["on" + type] = null;
        }
    },

    getEvent: function(event) {
        return event ? event : window.event;
    },

    getTarget: function(event) {
        return event.target || event.srcElement;
    },

    preventDefault: function(event) {
        if (event.preventDefault) {
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            event.returnValue = false;
        }
    },

    stopPropagation: function(event) {
        if (event.stopPropagation) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        } else {
            event.cancelBubble = true;
        }
    }
}

// Event delegation
Event.add(document,'click',function(event) {
    event = Event.getEvent(event);
    target = Event.getTarget(event);

    switch(target.id) {
        case 'linkLogin': // <li id="linkLogin> test </li> : works fine.
            entrance.style.display = 'block';
            break;

        case 'linkJoin': // <li id="linkJoin> <b> test </b> </li> : didn't work.
            alert('asdf');
            break;


        }       
    }
);
```

I really don't know why.

As I know, event capturing sequence will approach into the most lowest level of document if give 'true' option to event handler.

"window - document - body - elements father - elements son"

So if give an click event to 'document', the event will works if I click "elements son" inside document.

But this time was not. even if I give true or false option on event handler.

Is there any one who knows why?

Comment: The "linkJoin" element has all its content in a `<b>` container. When you click it, the target element will be that `<b>` and not the `<li>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about capturing vs bubbling phase. It's your use of event delegation: When you click on the `<b>` element, that element becomes the `target`, which does not have the expected id. You need to test all parent nodes of the target (until the `currentTarget`, i.e. `document` in your case) for being an element that you want to listen on.